# How to know which PMD rule fails?

Tags: java, maven, pmd

**Maven-pmd-plugin** used in the project. When I try to deploy the project, it fails with the following error:

*Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: PMD check threshold has been set to severity level 'error' - detected 1 violation(s) at that (or greater than that) level and 'failOnViolation' is true - failing the build*

How can I know which rule is fail? What violation is found?

Executing Maven with *-e* or *-X* does not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be a HTML report generated in `target/site/pmd.html` that lists detected issues (issue description and line).

Comment: I have target/pmd.xml. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can also build your project with the option `-Dpmd.printFailingErrors=true` or configure the maven plugin in the pom.xml file:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8</version>
    <configuration>
        <printFailingErrors>true</printFailingErrors>
    </configuration>
    ....
</plugin>
```

See https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/check-mojo.html#printFailingErrors

This will print out the rule violations directly in the console.